# Can't extract a value inside nested JSON using Jolt Transform

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I have this problem.

Given this sample JSON

```json
[
  {
    "aaa": "-",
    "name": "something_val",
    "bbb": "-",
    "is_active": true,
    "repository": null,
    "image_url": "some_val",
    "ccc_id_tmp": 2,
    "ddd_id_tmp": 3,
    "ccc_created_at": "timestamp",
    "updated_at": "timestamp",
    "result_ccc_id_lookup": {
      "ccc_id": "some_uuid"
    },
    "result_ddd_id_lookup": {
      "ddd_id": "some_uuid"
    }
  },
  {
    "aaa": "hi",
    "name": "something_val",
    "bbb": "yooo",
    "is_active": false,
    "repository": null,
    "image_url": "some_val",
    "ccc_id_tmp": 4,
    "ddd_id_tmp": 5,
    "ccc_created_at": "timestamp",
    "updated_at": "timestamp",
    "result_ccc_id_lookup": {
      "ccc_id": "some_uuid_2"
    },
    "result_ddd_id_lookup": {
      "ddd_id": "some_uuid_2"
    }
  }
]
```

The goal is I want to use Jolt Transform to extract the values inside **`result_ccc_id_lookup`** and **`result_ddd_id_lookup`**, meaning I will extract the **`ccc_id`** and **`ddd_id`** values.

So, the expected output will be like this

```json
{
  "aaa": "-",
  "name": "something_val",
  "bbb": "-",
  "is_active": true,
  "repository": null,
  "image_url": "some_val",
  "ccc_id_tmp": 2,
  "ddd_id_tmp": 3,
  "ccc_created_at": "timestamp",
  "updated_at": "timestamp",
  "ccc_id": "some_uuid",
  "ddd_id": "some_uuid"
}
```

Right now, I'm using this Jolt Transform to extract the value like the expected output

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "aaa": "[&1].aaa",
        "bbb": "[&1].bbb",
        "objective": "[&1].objective",
        "is_active": "[&1].is_active",
        "repository": "[&1].repository",
        "image_url": "[&1].image_url",
        "ccc_id_tmp": "[&1].ccc_id_tmp",
        "ddd_id_tmp": "[&1].ddd_id_tmp",
        "ccc_created_at": "[&1].ccc_created_at",
        "updated_at": "[&1].updated_at",
        "result_ccc_id_lookup": {
          "ccc_id": "[&1].ccc_id"
        },
        "result_ddd_id_lookup": {
          "ddd_id": "[&1].ddd_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But, the output is only like this. The **`ccc_id`** and **`ddd_id`** are missing

```json
{
  "aaa": "-",
  "name": "something_val",
  "bbb": "-",
  "is_active": true,
  "repository": null,
  "image_url": "some_val",
  "ccc_id_tmp": 2,
  "ddd_id_tmp": 3
}
```

Can you help me with this one? maybe something is wrong with my Jolt Transform?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to articulate every attribute one by one, but the following transformation is enough to express all

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",  // replicate all attributes those have the key which don't start with "result" 
        "result*": {    // other elements taken from the deeper level of one step
          "*": "[&2].&" // so increment the degree of identifier by 1, eg. [&1]->[&2]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]